# Bootstrap "row" causing 300ms input delay

Tags: bootstrap-4, delay

My app is too big to share the code but today something has broke. It was working just fine and suddenly 300ms click delay on mobile.

It seems that when anywhere on my page there is a `div` with class `row` (from bootstrap) the mobile version gets a 300ms click delay.

Remowing all `row` instantly fixes this problem. I have no idea where to search for this issue. My css doesn't overwrite any bootstrap classes.

Comment: can you host your project? without showing your project, we cant give any solution

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering @NishargShah. Sorry but the project is just too big and there are too many dependencies to post it. I thought it could be some popular problem and there is some known quick-fix

Comment: I think your problem is related to your internal CSS

Comment: cant go on guessing !!! atleast put that page's html  which is getting corrected after row removing!! cant hit the arrow in the dark!!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers - putting `touch-action: manipulation;` solved the issue. However I still have no clue why removing all `row`s also solved the issue